Gradle Version Mismatch with Java Build

My Gradle Wrapper settings are the following:

distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists


From the Compatibility Matrix in Gradle - it seems I can install Java Version 17? I used Eclipse Temurin 17.0.5 to work with it. Verified that JAVA_HOME is set. I also have the following in my build.gradle file

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
    }
}


I am getting error "Unsupported Class File Major Version 61" .Detailed stack trace from one of the many...

java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting sun/text/resources/cldr/ext/FormatData_en_GB.
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_1f1cc91.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:93)
        at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:244)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:541)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1108)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:182)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:741)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:637)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:545)
        at jdk.localedata/sun.util.resources.provider.LocaleDataProvider.loadResourceBundle(LocaleDataProvider.java:54)
        at jdk.localedata/sun.util.resources.provider.LocaleDataProvider.getBundle(LocaleDataProvider.java:40)
        at java.base/sun.util.resources.Bundles$2.run(Bundles.java:270)
        at java.base/sun.util.resources.Bundles$2.run(Bundles.java:265)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at java.base/sun.util.resources.Bundles.loadBundleFromProviders(Bundles.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.util.resources.Bundles.findBundleOf(Bundles.java:201)
        at java.base/sun.util.resources.Bundles.loadBundleOf(Bundles.java:145)
        at java.base/sun.util.resources.Bundles.of(Bundles.java:106)
        at java.base/sun.util.resources.LocaleData$1.run(LocaleData.java:186)
        at java.base/sun.util.resources.LocaleData$1.run(LocaleData.java:183)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at java.base/sun.util.resources.LocaleData.getBundle(LocaleData.java:183)
        at java.base/sun.util.resources.LocaleData.getDateFormatData(LocaleData.java:146)
        at java.base/java.text.DateFormatSymbols.initializeData(DateFormatSymbols.java:745)
        at java.base/java.text.DateFormatSymbols.<init>(DateFormatSymbols.java:151)
        at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.DateFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.getInstance(DateFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.java:85)
        at java.base/java.text.DateFormatSymbols.getProviderInstance(DateFormatSymbols.java:370)
        at java.base/java.text.DateFormatSymbols.getInstanceRef(DateFormatSymbols.java:360)
        at java.base/java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:626)
        at java.base/java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:603)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.getLastResortErrorLogFile(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:162)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:111)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
        at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
        at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while instrumenting sun/text/resources/cldr/ext/FormatData_en_GB.
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_1f1cc91.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrumentError(Instrumenter.java:170)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_1f1cc91.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:120)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_1f1cc91.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:91)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_1f1cc91.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:184)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_1f1cc91.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_1f1cc91.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:152)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_1f1cc91.core.internal.instr.InstrSupport.classReaderFor(InstrSupport.java:247)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_1f1cc91.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:86)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_1f1cc91.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:118)

I am running everything from command line (MacOS terminal). What do I have to do to get the ./gradlew build working successfully?
Regards,

Do you have more detail on the error? You can get a stacktrace with ./gradlew build -s

@SimonJacobs    what information am I really looking for? Should I see something specific? and I have updated the question with even larger stack trace. But that's all I have got after using -s

Thanks for the stacktrace, which doesn't suggest a solution to me unfortunately. Seems it truly is just, as you say, a Java compatability issue,  and one right in the startup phase of Gradle. Maybe you could run ./gradlew --version to confirm that all the versions of everything are as you think they are

It was simply an issue of version upgrade. It was to do with what version my Mockito and Jacoco were in. I upgraded Mockito to 5.0.0 and Jacoco to 0.8.8 and it removed pretty much all similar errors.
I am still down with errors but they are for different reasons and this thread isn't in context.
